# Map<String, Map<String, Car>> to List<Car> using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, flatten

Let's say that I have the structure described in the title:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Car>> mapNeighborhood
```

that contains all cars in a neighborhood indexed by address and plate respectively.
I want to select all red cars to repaint them in black. To accomplish that task, I have tried to "flat" both Maps and obtain a List using Java 8. Once I got the List, applying a Predicate I can select only the red cars and apply the repainting.

```
List<Car> listCars = new ArrayList<Car>();

mapNeighborhood.values().forEach(map -> map.values()
                                           .forEach(car -> listCars.add(car)));

listCars.stream().filter(Car::isRed)
                 .forEach(car -> car.repaint(Color.Black));
```

I'm sure that you can achieve the same using just one line in Java 8, but I think that you may lose legibility.

My question is: Is there another less verbose way of flattening the Maps into a List? Maybe using `flatMap`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mapNeighborhood.values().forEach(value->value.values().forEach(car -> rePiantIfRed(car)));`

Comment: @HadiJ Well, that's pretty much my original solution but hidding the filtering inside a method 'repaintIfRed'. Thanks for commenting anyway.

Comment: @HadiJ I've removed a superfluous stream() applying your approach. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need an intermediate `List`

```
mapNeighborhood.values().stream()
                        .flatMap(byPlate -> byPlate.values().stream())
                        .filter(Car::isRed)
                        .forEach(car -> car.repaint(Color.Black))
```

I think this is both *more* readable than your code and shorter. It is also objectively **much** more efficient, both in time and space.

---

Also note that `Car::isRed` is somewhat odd as you would need a check for every possible `Color` on `Car` - add a new `color` for the season, reimplement `Car`.

`Color::isRed` makes much more sense, with `Car` implements `Colored` or some such

```
interface Colored {
    Color getColor();
}

// in Color
public static boolean isRed(Colored colored) {
    return Objects.equals(colored.getColor(), RED);
}
```

Comment: You're right, your solution is perfectly readable and more efficient than mine. :-) That's what I was looking for. I felt that mine was too verbose and ineficcient. My real class is not Car, this is not homework, method Car::isRed is just a simile but I'll keep in mine what you have stated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

My result is the same with @Boris, but I will show you how to achieve it with IntelliJ:

```
for (Map<String, Car> value : mapNeighborhood.values()) {
    for (Car car : value.values()) {
        if (car.isRed()) {
            car.repaint(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you move your cursor into the first "for" word, press Alt-Enter then choose "Replace with ForEach", tada, here we go:

```
mapNeighborhood.values().stream()
                        .flatMap(value -> value.values().stream())
                        .filter(Car::isRed)
                        .forEach(car -> car.repaint(Color.BLACK));
```

With any kind of loop, you can try to use IntelliJ to help you convert to java 8 style intelligently

Comment: Nice trick! I work with Eclipse and I'm not familiar with IntelliJ but I like your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way i tried

```
List<Car> collect = mapNeighborhood.values().stream()
                                            .map(Map::values)
                                            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then you can go ahead and manipulate the list of Cars.

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpfull.

```
mapNeighborhood.values().stream()
                        .map(Map::values)
                        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                        .filter(car -> car.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("red"))
                        .forEach(car -> car.repaint("black"));
```